# How to import all the modules from the current directory

Tags: python, import

I would like to import automatically, and dynamically, all the files from the current directory. I have, for example the structure as follow:

```
/ my_project
  |- GeneralDriverAbstract.py
  |- A_Driver.py # Child of Abstract class
  |- A_DriverAlpha.py
  |- A_DriverBeta.py
  |- B_Driver.py # Child of Abstract class
  |- B_DriverAlpha.py
  |- B_DriverBeta.py
  |- Suffix.py
  |- other_files.py
```

In `GeneralDriverAbstract` I would like to import all the class that are in the same directory. Indeed, When the user will create a driver (A, B or other in future), it will pass to the `init` of the abstract class its name (`A_Driver`, `B_Driver`...) and the suffix parameter (`alpha`, `beta`...) that is defined in the enumeration in `Suffix.py`. Then it wil make proper configuraitions by creating the object matching deviceDriver+suffix.

How can I import all the modules? I want my code to be dynamic, so if we need to add more devices, we will just need to create files and add suffix inside the enumeration, without modifying the abstract class.

I tried two approaches. First, writing an `__init__.py` file with this inside:

```py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

And then using `from . import *` but it is not working. I got name error, for example:
`test = A_Driver()` gives `NameError: name 'A_Driver' is not defined`.

The second approach was to move the code of the init file inside the abstract class as follow:

```py
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
module_files = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith(('__init__.py', __file__))]

print(module_files)

# Import each module dynamically
for file in module_files:
    importlib.import_module(file)
```

But even if I removed the abstract file from the list, it looks like I have a recursive inclusion. Maybe from the imports of the drivers' classes (I have twice printed the `module_files` array).
I also have a name error. I also tried with `__import__` but I got same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I changed my code a bit to avoid recursive inclusion by importing only the required module (the calling driver class + the specified suffix), and I also changed the `eval` function to the `getattr` one:

```py
module_to_import = driver_class.__name__ + suffix.value
module = importlib.import_module(module_to_import)
my_object = getattr(module, module_to_import)
```

I don't know why `eval` couldn't work.